# Rails: Adding up values from a form without complex models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I`m looking to create a form where upon submission, all the values from the form are added up together.

At the same time I would define a session within the controller so later the added up values can be written into the DB.

views/quiz/new.html.erb :

```
<% form_tag do %>
        <%= form_tag(:controller => "quiz", :action => "new", :method => "post") %>
        <div id="container">
        <p class="question">The glass is...</p>
        <ul>
            <%= radio_button_tag :value, '2' %>
            <li>Half full.</li><br>
            <%= radio_button_tag :value, '1' %>
            <li>Half empty.</li><br>
            <%= radio_button_tag :value, '3' %>
            <li>What glass?</li><br>
        </ul>


<p class="question">When does the narwhal bacon?</p>
            <ul>
                <%= radio_button_tag :value, '2' %>
                <li>Tomorrow.</li><br>
                <%= radio_button_tag :value, '1' %>
                <li>Midnight.</li><br>
                <%= radio_button_tag :value, '3' %>
                <li>Mmm, I love bacon.</li><br>
            </ul>

         <p class="right">
            <%= submit_tag "Submit Answers", :class => "submit_button" %>
        </p>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

Don`t quite know how the controller would look like for this though.

How would I add the selected values together upon submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum = 0
params.each_pair do |key, value|
  sum += value.to_i
end

# sum now has your added values
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters (from the URL, and the form elements) are passed into your controller actions.

Basically, you can take those parameters (they're strings), convert the relevant ones to integers, and just add them up, and store that value in the DB.

Here's a tutorial that I hope will help out, explaining how to use parameters in controllers:

http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6371-action-controller-parameters